# Delphi method to remove illegal chars from string before adding to JSON

Tags: json, delphi

I'm looking for a method to ensure that illegal chars has been "escaped" or whatever it's called from a string before adding the string to an JSON object and sending it.

The purpose is to resturn data from a dataset to clients using rest and JSON, since there can be illegal chars in the dataset I'm guess I need to handle the strings before returning the result data to the clients (server side) and on client side I'll need to decode those string back again.

I havent found any "utils" in delphi for it, but surely they must exist?

E.g. illegal string "**Bygning 9O \Ventilation \Anlæg 07A \Varmeflade \Alarm frostsikring**" where the backslash is a problem.

What would be the best way to handle this? I don't even know which chars are illegal.

```
procedure TRestWebModule.AlarmsGet(Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse);
var
  a: TJSONArray;
  o: TJSONObject;
  includeOOS : Boolean;
  s : string;
begin
  includeOOS := False;
  // Load query parameters.
  if Request.QueryFields.Count > 0 then
    includeOOS := StrToBoolDef(Request.QueryFields.values['includeOOS'], False);

  Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.Close;
  Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.ParamByName('@includeOOS').Value := includeOOS;
  Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.Active := True;

  // Put results in a JSON object...

  if Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.Active then begin
    if Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.RecordCount > 0 then begin
      a := TJSONArray.Create;
      try
        Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.First;
        while (not Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.Eof) do
        begin
          o := TJSONObject.Create;
          o.AddPair('EventId',TJSONNumber.Create( Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('EventId').AsInteger ));
          o.AddPair('FriendlyName',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('mod_FriendlyName').AsString );
          o.AddPair('SiteName',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('SiteName').AsAnsiString );

          o.AddPair('AlarmReservedByUser',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('AlarmReservedByUser').AsString );
          o.AddPair('AlarmState',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('AlarmState').AsString );
          o.AddPair('WorkflowState',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('WorkflowState').AsString );
          o.AddPair('AlarmCounter',TJSONNumber.Create( Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('AlarmCounter').AsInteger ));
          o.AddPair('Priority',TJSONNumber.Create( Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('Priority').AsInteger ));

          o.AddPair('TechnicalAddress',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('TechnicalAddress').AsString );
          o.AddPair('AlarmAlias',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('AlarmAlias').AsString );

          // excape chars are a problem
          s := Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('AlarmMessage').AsString;
        //  o.AddPair('AlarmMessage', s );

          o.AddPair('EventText',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('EventText').AsString );
          o.AddPair('CallListName',Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('CallListName').AsString );

          o.AddPair('EventTime', TJSONNumber.Create( Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.FieldByName('EventDateTime').AsFloat ) );

          a.AddElement(o);
          Ad_fetchalarmhistoryProc.Next;
        end;
      finally
        Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
        Response.Content := a.ToString;
        a.DisposeOf;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Update:**

I got this error in firefox when calling `localhost:8080/alarms`

**Changing from a.Tostring to a.ToJSON Solves it.**

But I would prefer not having to do that. It might again happen with other characters.

It appears only to be a problem when using a browser to test the response, when I use a Delphi REST client there are no problems consuming the JSON.

Comment: See [How can I replace a special characters in a given string with space or without space by using delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21979184/576719).

Comment: Oh wow, I've never used the JSON tools built-in to Delphi, I use Super Object... but I am shocked to learn that you're responsible to format the string *before* passing into a JSON object. By nature, I'm used to Super Object doing that for me automatically. That's one of the main reasons to use a library to serialize JSON at all in the first place!

Comment: @Jerry The built in library handles escaping fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's what I assumed, of course - essentially my point. I find it extremely hard to believe that such an error could occur, as I understand the question. I guess you didn't get the sarcasm of my comment :-)

Comment: If it only happens when using a browser, then it sounds like the browser's attempt to get a `favicon`. Is this the handler for all requests? Or just one?

Comment: @Jerry Sarcasm isn't terribly reliable. Better to speak clearly. In any case it would take an incredible read to detect sarcasm in that post and my money is that you added the sarcasm after my response.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The point was "That's one of the main reasons to use a library to serialize JSON at all in the first place". Yes, I'm surprised to hear OP has such a problem. But please explain how your last comment has any benefit at all to the question other than to talk down to me?

Comment: @JerryDodge Well then perhaps I have no idea what you meant when you introduced sarcasm to the conversation. I guess only you truly know at what point the sarcasm was applied.

Comment: Can this issue be caused by the contenttype 
Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

It works for the Delphi REST client and nordic chars gets transfered as expected, but a browser would not expect chars as "\" ?
No it's not a favicon issue, as soon as the single "\" is removed or replaced by a \\ or something else, it works in FF, IE will try to open VS because it's set as standard app for JSON on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddeling around whit this problem, I found the solution.

The problem is in the final section

```
  finally
    Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    Response.Content := a.ToString; // incorrect
    a.DisposeOf;
  end;
```

I should be like this

```
  finally
    Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    Response.Content := a.ToJSON; // correct
    a.DisposeOf;
  end;
```

Then the framework will encode everything correct. Just wanted to share that, maybe someone else will run into that problem using the Tostring.